# Switch between several connected USB mice on Windows

Tags: windows, usb, mouse

I have a Windows computer with two simple plug-n-play USB mice connected. By default, both mice have control over the pointer. I am looking for a tool/command line command that allows me to switch one mouse off temporarily.

Comment: I don't believe what you want is possible unless you disable/enable the device yourself.  What version of Windows are you using exactly?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve by doing this? It sounds like it would be easily solved by simply not using the other mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use utility called `DevCon.exe`, it's available somewhere at Microsoft Download center or thanks to SlySoft in `http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html`.

Install Virtual Clone Drive and copy `DevCon.exe` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Elaborate Bytes\VirtualCloneDrive` to `C:\Windows\System32`.

Then find Vendor and Part ID of your mouse. Run Windows device manager `devmgmt.msc`, select properties of your mouse and find ID string:

[image]

At last, run from cmd or save to `.bat` file: `DevCon.exe disable HID\VID_045E&PID_0745*` and `DevCon.exe enable HID\VID_045E&PID_0745*`. (replace with your mouse dev ID)

Use `DevCon.exe Help` for more info.